# why scanf can change other variable which is not argument？

Tags: c

Here is code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    unsigned char mem[32];

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<32;i++){
        unsigned char a[8];
        scanf("%s",a);
        for(j = 0;j<8;j++){
            mem[i] <<=1;
            mem[i] |= a[j] == '0' ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
...
}
```

Input is a number in binary representation. I want to read them and store them into unsigned char array. When i equals 0, mem[0] = 0x3E. But when i equals 1, mem[0] will change to 0x0 as soon as scanf execute. And other inputs is fine. I have no idea about it. Input as follow

```
00111110
10100000
01010000
11100000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00111111
10000000
00000010
11000010
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
11111111
10001001
```

Comment: @ASON CHAN The code does not make a sense and has undefined behavior.

Comment: `mem` is uninitialized, so you don't know what you'll get with `mem[i]`.

Comment: @ASON CHAN The array mem is not initialized. If you want to enter a string containing 8 characters then the array a shall be declared as having at least 9 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by having `scanf()` write out-of-bounds of the array `a`.

8-character strings like `00111110` will occupy 9 bytes of the memory including the terminating null-character, so you have to allocate enough buffer.

Also you should limit the number of characters to read to prevent buffer overrun.

Another point is that you should check if `scanf()` succeeded to read what is expected.

There also is another *undefined behavior*: you used values of `mem[i]`, which is uninitialized non-static local variable. Such values are indeterminate and mustn't be used in calculations.

In conclusion, the part

```c
unsigned char a[8];
scanf("%s",a);
```

should be

```
char a[9];
if (scanf("%8s",a) != 1) {
    fputs("read error\n", stderr);
    return 1;
}
mem[i] = 0;
```

Also note that I used `char` instead of `unsigned char` because `%s` format specifier expects `char*` and there aren't seem any code that should require `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is too short it has to be `char a[9]` to accommodate null terminating character. Also use `scanf("%8s",a);`